# Number of spanning forests in undirected graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to find out the number of spanning forests in the undirected graph which is shown below in the link. I know what a spanning tree is, but I don't exactly understand the spanning forest term. All I know is that it's a subgraph that must be acyclic, but I'm not sure what the spanning in this connection means. Any direction would be appreciated!

[Undirected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyhxg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone agrees on the term 'spanning forest' but given your graph, the task is most likely to come up with spanning trees for each of the two connected subgraphs.

So, basically you have to figure out how many spanning trees there are for each those two subgraphs, and multiply those two numbers